# custom attribute setter error when data binding - Android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-custom-attributes

I have custom attribute which is declared as type of string, when a pass the value as just string in xml like this `app:cpb_title="sometsring"` its working but when i try data binding like this `app:cpb_title"@{model.someStringField}"` it gaves me error **"cannot find setter  for "app:cpb_title" that accepts parameter type  java.lang.String"**

how can i fix it?

attrs.xml

```
  <declare-styleable name="CircularProgressBar">
    <attr name="cpb_hasShadow" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="cpb_progressColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cpb_backgroundColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cpb_title" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cpb_titleColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cpb_subtitle" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cpb_subtitleColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cpb_strokeWidth" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

inside view class

```
 String t = a.getString(R.styleable.CircularProgressBar_cpb_title);
    if(t!=null)
        mTitle = t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) instead of declaring attributes in the `attrs.xml` file. Please do as below:

```
class BindingUtil {

    @BindingAdapter("cpb_title")
    public static void setTitle(TextView view, String title) {
        view.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `app:cpb_title` attribute in your XML as below:

```
               <Textview
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cpb_title="@{model.someStringField}" />
```

Comment: thanks for answer, where can i put this @BindingAdapter("cpb_title") ? inside the model class? or inside custom view class

Comment: you can place any class. Put in model class